# Python stop sniffing upon specific condition

Tags: python, object, scapy, packet-sniffers

I found some questions regarding **an object deleting itself**. But nowhere mentioned a suitable example where such action is required. But take the below example.

```
from scapy.all import *

class x():
    def me(self):
        self.i=0
        sniff(iface="em1", filter='tcp', prn=self.my_callback)

    def my_callback(self, pkt):
        print pkt.summary()
        self.i+=1
        if self.i>10:
            self.__del__()

    def __del__(self):
        print self
        return

y=x()
y.me()
print y
```

In this case, the `sniff` function will continue infinitely. I want to stop it and delete the `object` if I receive `10 pkts`. So the deletion of the object should be initiated from within.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you want that? Objects/variables get deleted if they are out of scope. I dont think that it is possible to actually for an object to delete itself like you want.

Comment: I can do a multiprocess, add the object name to a `queue` when I want to delete it and from another process I'll access the `queue` and delete the object. But I cannot do that until and unless I stop sniff first. But isn't it going towards a bit complex?

Comment: `__del__()` is the *finalizer* —it is *NOT* the same as a destructor in C++.  There is no guarantee that `__del__` will *ever* get called, and calling it explicitly does not guarantee that the object is not still live.

Comment: @DietrichEpp That's not the correct syntax. I know. I just mentioned that there to inform that I want to start the deletion process there.

Comment: @RatDon: Nothing to do with syntax here... you can't actually delete an object in Python, there is no syntax for it.  `del x` will delete a reference to the object, `del x[i]` will delete an element from an array, and `__del__()` is the finalizer... but nothing in Python gives you the ability to delete an object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the goal is to stop `sniff` when you receive a specific packet from a specific IP, then the correct approach is to pass in a `stop_filter` to the `sniff` function, as specified in the documentation, copied below.

```
>>> print sniff.__doc__
Sniff packets
sniff([count=0,] [prn=None,] [store=1,] [offline=None,] [lfilter=None,] + L2ListenSocket args) -> list of packets

  count: number of packets to capture. 0 means infinity
  store: wether to store sniffed packets or discard them
    prn: function to apply to each packet. If something is returned,
         it is displayed. Ex:
         ex: prn = lambda x: x.summary()
lfilter: python function applied to each packet to determine
         if further action may be done
         ex: lfilter = lambda x: x.haslayer(Padding)
offline: pcap file to read packets from, instead of sniffing them
timeout: stop sniffing after a given time (default: None)
L2socket: use the provided L2socket
opened_socket: provide an object ready to use .recv() on
stop_filter: python function applied to each packet to determine
             if we have to stop the capture after this packet
             ex: stop_filter = lambda x: x.haslayer(TCP)
```

Here is some sample code that will stop sniffing on a packet from a particular IP.

```
from scapy.all import *

def stopfilter(x):
     if x[IP].dst == '23.212.52.66':
         return True
     else
         return False

sniff(iface="wlan0", filter='tcp', stop_filter=stopfilter)
```

Comment: Is it a different version of `scapy`. I'm unable to find the `stop_filter` in my `sniff.__doc__`.

Comment: @RatDon, I'm using 2.2.0. I'm not sure which version this was introduced in.

Comment: It's introduced in the `scapy 2.2.0` only. I was using `scapy 2.1.0` and it was not there. Though `2.2.0` has been released from 2011, it was not there in Fedora Repository. I installed `scapy` 3 months back and it installed `2.1.0`. Anyhow, I upgraded `scapy`. And it's working Fine. Thanks.

Comment: @RatDon, Good to know for future reference. Also, please accept the answer if it resolved your problem and update the title of your question.

Answer (score 5):

```
sniff(other_args=other_values, count=10)
#                              ^^^^^
```

The solution here isn't to destroy the object. If you somehow managed to destroy the object, scapy would just crash horribly or do crazy things when it tried to use a destroyed object.

Comment: I just gave a simple example. I want to stop `sniff` when I receive a `specific packet` from a `specific IP`. So I cannot use `count`. :'(